# Disable SharePlay / screen sharing on iOS 15

Tags: ios, facetime, ios15

iOS 15 introduces the ability for people to share their screen via FaceTime (https://www.apple.com/uk/newsroom/2021/06/ios-15-brings-powerful-new-features-to-stay-connected-focus-explore-and-more/) - from a developer POV, is there a way to disable this for my app?

I can't find any information on how this might be possible and, similar to screenshot functionality, I fully expect that the answer is **no**.

However, I've been asked to investigate - hence this question.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017687 ?

Comment: @Paulw11 - that looks like it does the trick actually. Can't believe I didn't think of that! If you want to post that as an answer I'll happily accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't opt-out as such, but you can detect that screen sharing is active and adapt your UI in response.  For example, you could overlay a view stating "Screen sharing not available" or similar.

Apple describes this technique in [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017687) but, in summary:

You can listen for the [`capturedDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921652-captureddidchangenotification#) notification and when you receive this notification, you check the [`isCaptured`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-iscaptured) property of `UIScreen` - If it is true then the screen is being shared to some external destination; This could be via a screen recording a broadcast extension, AirPlay, Quicktime capture via cable or the new SharePlay feature, but you probably want to handle all of these in the same way.